# Django Operation Error after saved objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

This keep popping up on web after save an object, not sure what happens: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZQgw.png)

*OperationalError at /admin/product/product/add/
no such table: product_product
Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/product/add/
Django Version:    3.1.2
Exception Type:    OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: product_product*

My code:

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import product

admin.site.register(product)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class product(models.Model):
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=222)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=333, decimal_places=2)
    summary     = models.TextField(default = 'this is cool!')
    feature     = models.BooleanField()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ProductConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'product'
```

Comment: Did you make and run all migrations?

Comment: Yeah I missed typing app file name after makemigrations in terminal, no wonder it said no change detected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's migration problem, if it states **No changes detected**, it doesn't mean no change needed to be made, as what I missed is the `app file` name typed after `makemigrations` in terminal.